# Task Error when await in windows store application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, async-await, windows-store

Hej, I have a method:

```
    public static async Task<myClassl> GetData()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http:sasa.com");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/GetData");
        myClassl data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<myClassl>();

        return data ;
    }
```

And when I write

```
myClassl  t = await DataGetter.GetData();
```

I have:
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: have you tried what the compiler has suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flag your method `async` where you write:

```
// Add async to your calling method
private async Task SomeOtherMethod()
{
    myClassl t = await DataGetter.GetData();
```

Any method that uses `await` internally must be an `async` method itself.